# How to pass a jquery get string to a php script

Tags: php, jquery, get, urlencode

I'm sure this has been asked many times but I couldn't find the answer after quite a bit of searching.

I have a simple jquery ajax request to get some data for a particular string as follows:

```
$.ajax( 
   { url: "/getval.php?title="+encodeURIComponent(title), 
     dataType:"json", 
     success: function(data) { console.log(data) } 
   });
```

The php script is using:

```
$title = urldecode($_GET["title"]);
```

to get the value from the get request.
It doesn't need to work for every conceivable string but I do need it to work for a string with a single quote. What is the safest (and easiest) way to do this request and handle the request in php?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: You don't need to urldecode $_get, it is already done for you by PHP.

Comment: also, you should send it with the "data" attribute of the jQuery object parameter, this takes care of escaping and other stuff for you and is more maintainable :
data: {"title":titleval}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why hard way?

jQuery:

```
$.get("/getval.php", { title: 'your title' },
   function(data){
     console.log(data);
  }
);
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$title = $_GET['title'];
```

Please always read manual first:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `data` attribute, and PHP will get the value from the `$_GET` array:

```
$.ajax( 
   { url: "/getval.php", 
     dataType:"json",
     data: { title: 'the title' },
     success: function(data) { console.log(data) } 
   });
```